# Is it Meteor support installation in Windows 8 officially?

Tags: meteor, installation

We successfully setup the Meteor 0.7.1.2 in Centos. Is it Latest version supporting installation in  windows 8 officially?. If yes please share the information.

we know its supporting unofficially with the following url

http://win.meteor.com

Thanks
Ramu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree about the cloud solutions. I've used the unofficial Windows version and had some problems, but I am loving cloud development with Meteor.

If you are interested in trying it out, I wrote up an entire tutorial on how to get set up with cloud development in Meteor and included a screencast.

http://simpleprogrammer.com/2014/10/13/getting-started-meteor-tutorial-cloud/

Answer (score 1):

Windows support is not yet official and win.meteor.com outlines some workarounds, the better ones which include utilizing a virtual machine. There is a suggested native solution (launchmeteor.exe), although unofficial, with key difference (for some developers) being Meteorite not work on Windows yet.

According to the roadmap trello board https://trello.com/c/ZMvnfMfI/11-official-windows-support official windows support is targeted for 1.0 if time permits, but it seems very unlikely.

For interim portability, you may want to have a look at cloud solutions like nitrous.io at http://help.nitrous.io/meteor-app/ which runs the dev environment on the cloud but has a windows desktop app http://blog.nitrous.io/2014/02/25/nitrous-desktop-is-now-available-for-windows.html which at least lets you develop locally and sync to your nitrous.io cloud box.

Comment: win.meteor.com has a working albeit unofficial native Windows version. Probably the key difference for some developers is that Meteorite (an unofficial package manager) does not currently work on Windows (however, there is a project to get it working).

Comment: @StephenD thanks I've updated the answer and please go ahead for further edits for anything you feel will contribute to complete this answer